# Why jpa repository / Hibernate write the same query in the console

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Why jpa repository write the same query in the eclipse console ?
it excute theme many ?

```
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_,   technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_,       technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
 Hibernate: select technicald0_.CTC_ID as CTC_ID1_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_CLASSIF as CTC_PANI9_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_PANIER_STAT as CTC_PAN10_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_COMMENTAIRE_TECH as VEH_COMM2_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_NBR_DIFFUS as CTC_NBR_3_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_GENERATION_TECH as VEH_GENE4_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_DATE_MODIFICATION as CTC_DATE5_7_0_, technicald0_.CTC_MODIFICATEUR_ID as CTC_MOD11_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PHASE as VEH_PHAS6_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_ETAT as VEH_ETAT7_7_0_, technicald0_.VEH_PONDERATION as VEH_POND8_7_0_ from SRA_COTA_TECHNIQUES technicald0_ where technicald0_.CTC_ID=?
```

My query is is :

```
Cart findByRefVehicle(VehicleFinalized one);
```

i have Cart class && VehicleFinalzed class && TechnicalData class, there's relation beetween cart to TechnicalData and VehicleFinalized to TechnicalData

My ENtity Class is :

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedAttributeNode;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraph;
import javax.persistence.NamedEntityGraphs;
import javax.persistence.NamedSubgraph;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.transaction.NotSupportedException;

import com.normasys.entity.reference.Brand;
import com.normasys.entity.reference.Model;
import com.normasys.entity.technical.TechnicalData;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "SRA_VEHICULE_FIN", uniqueConstraints = {       @UniqueConstraint(name = "UNIQUE_VEH_FIN_SRA", columnNames = { "VEH_CODE_SRA" }) })
@DiscriminatorValue(Environment.FINAL)
@NamedEntityGraphs({
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "VehicleFinalized.full", attributeNodes = {       @NamedAttributeNode("bodywork"), @NamedAttributeNode("supply"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("energy"), @NamedAttributeNode("price"),    @NamedAttributeNode("classification"), @NamedAttributeNode("identification"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("motorization"),     @NamedAttributeNode("suspensionAndBraking"), @NamedAttributeNode("dimensionAndWeight"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("securityElement"),     @NamedAttributeNode("drivingAssistance") },
        subclassSubgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(name = "VehicleFinalized.full.model", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("brand") })),
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "VehicleFinalized.properties_only", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("bodywork"),       @NamedAttributeNode("supply"),
                @NamedAttributeNode("energy") }) })
public class VehicleFinalized extends AbstractVehicle {

// private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(VehiculeFinalized.class);

@JoinColumn(name = "VEH_CREATE_FROM", nullable = true, foreignKey =           @ForeignKey(name = "FK_VEH_FIN_CRF"))
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, orphanRemoval = true)
private Vehicle createdFrom;

@Column(name = "VEH_CODE_SRA", length = 7, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String codeSRA;

@Column(name = "VEH_NUM_ORDRE", nullable = false)
private Integer orderNumber;

@Column(name = "VEH_CODE_SEQUENCE")
private Integer sequenceCode;

@JoinColumn(name = "VEH_PRIX_COUT", nullable = false, foreignKey =  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_VEH_FIN_PCF"))
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
protected PriceFinalized price = new PriceFinalized();

@JoinColumn(name = "VEH_CLASSIFICATION", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_VEH_FIN_CLS"))
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
protected ClassificationFinalized classification = new ClassificationFinalized();

@JoinColumn(name = "VEH_DONNEE_TECHNIQUE", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_VEH_FIN_CTC"))
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH,
        CascadeType.REMOVE })
protected TechnicalData technicalData = new TechnicalData();

public VehicleFinalized() {
}

public VehicleFinalized(final VehicleFinalized vehicle) {
    environment = Environment.FINAL;

    createdFrom = vehicle.getCreatedFrom();
    codeSRA = vehicle.getCodeSRA();
    orderNumber = vehicle.getOrderNumber();
    sequenceCode = vehicle.getSequenceCode();

    price = vehicle.getPrice().clone();
    classification = vehicle.getClassification().clone();
    technicalData = vehicle.getTechnicalData().clone();

    copyFields(vehicle);
}

public VehicleFinalized(final Vehicle vehicle, final Integer sequenceCode, final Integer orderNumber) throws NotSupportedException {
    createdFrom = vehicle;
    environment = Environment.FINAL;
    this.sequenceCode = sequenceCode;
    this.orderNumber = orderNumber;

    copyFields(vehicle);

    codeSRA = VehicleFinalizedUtil.generateCodeSRA(model.getBrand().getCode(), model.getCode(), sequenceCode);
    price = new PriceFinalized(vehicle.getPrice());
    classification = new ClassificationFinalized(vehicle.getClassification());

}




public VehicleFinalized(final Long id, final String codeSRA, final String model, final String brand) {
    super();
    setId(id);
    this.codeSRA = codeSRA;
    this.model = new Model();
    this.model.setTitle(model);
    this.model.setBrand(new Brand());
    this.model.getBrand().setTitle(brand);
}

@Override
public boolean calculateCompleted() {
    return uncompleted == 0 || getBrand() != null && model != null && bodywork != null && supply != null && energy != null && version != null
            && administrativePower != null
            && identification.calculateCompleted() && motorization.calculateCompleted() && suspensionAndBraking.calculateCompleted()
            && dimensionAndWeight.calculateCompleted() && securityElement.calculateCompleted() && price.calculateCompleted()
            && classification.calculateCompleted() && drivingAssistance.calculateCompleted();
}

public Vehicle getCreatedFrom() {
    return createdFrom;
}

public void setCreatedFrom(final Vehicle createdFrom) {
    this.createdFrom = createdFrom;
}

public String getCodeSRA() {
    return codeSRA;
}

public void setCodeSRA(final String codeSRA) {
    this.codeSRA = codeSRA;
}

public Integer getOrderNumber() {
    return orderNumber;
}

public void setOrderNumber(final Integer orderNumber) {
    this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
}

@Override
public PriceFinalized getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(final PriceFinalized price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public ClassificationFinalized getClassification() {
    return classification;
}

public void setClassification(final ClassificationFinalized classification) {
    this.classification = classification;
}

public TechnicalData getTechnicalData() {
    return technicalData;
}

public void setTechnicalData(final TechnicalData technicalData) {
    this.technicalData = technicalData;
}

public Integer getSequenceCode() {
    return sequenceCode;
}

public void setSequenceCode(final Integer sequenceCode) {
    this.sequenceCode = sequenceCode;
}

@Override
public void setCompletedFlag() {
    uncompleted = calculateCompleted() ? 0 : 1;

}
```

}

Comment: please also post you Entity classes and the implementation of Cart findByRefVehicle(VehicleFinalized one);

Comment: Thank you for your response Zulfi, i have posted the code of my entity

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends how you configure your fetch strategy.

If your attribute are configured as Eager then at each time you will load an object, you will load the associated object and then make a request to your database. You can use a Lazy strategy if you do not want load the associated object.

Finally you can also configure a hibernate cache to not play several times the same resquest.

Comment: i use LAZY and EAGER configuration

Comment: i will try with hibernate cache and let you knew